# Reverse combination issue with Regex

Tags: .net, regex

I am working on a validation issue using Regex.The below regex will accepts only data starts with HN or MY , followed by 8 digits. But it also accepts the NH or YM combinations too. How to prevent that ?

`Regex reg;
reg = new Regex(@"^[HN|hn]{2}|[MY|my]{2}[0-9]{8}");`

Condition
 - Total Length 10 (2 characters + 8 digits)
 - Starts with HN or hn or MY or my

I am able to achieve partially, but this regex allows when the data will come in 
**NH11111111** (N and H is allowed as the first two chars and followed by eight 1). Is there any possible to change the regex, so that it should accept only 
**hn,hN,Hn,HN,my,mY,My,MY** and not **NH,YM (reverse combinations)**

Valid Strings

- HN11111111
- MY11111111
- hn23456789
- my23456789
- hN23456789
- My23456789

Invalid Strings

- HY11111111
- HM11111111
- HM111111
- **NH11111111**
- **YM11111111** (Currently last and second last are allowed).

Thanks in advance(I am using .NET 4.5).

Comment: Use `[Hh][Nn]` or even `HN` with a case-insensitivity flag.

Comment: what about [this](https://regex101.com/r/KoZ1Aa/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex, `^[HN|hn]{2}|[MY|my]{2}[0-9]{8}`, is "corrupt" because of two things at least:

- The `|` alternation operator without a grouping construct "splits" the pattern into two alternatives, one (`^[HN|hn]{2}`) matches `H`, `h`, N`,`n`or`|`twice at the start of the string (and it can be followed with anything), and the`[MY|my]{2}[0-9]{8}`part matches`M`,`m`,`Y`,`y`or`|` twice and then any 8 digits anywhere inside the string (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG52un/3))
- The `[HN|hn]` matches a *single* char because `[...]` define a *character* class, not a group of alternative patterns. You need to use round brackets, `(...)` (capturing) or `(?:...)` (non-capturing).

You may use

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^(?:HN|hn|MY|my)[0-9]{8}$");
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6XUzkf/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:HN|hn|MY|my)` - `HN`, `MY`, `hn`, `my` substring
- `[0-9]{8}` - 8 digits
- `$` - end of string.